# Find UK daily flow discharge data with gaps in the time series

Tags: data-request, time-series

I am looking for 2 UK hydrological gauges (one main river and one stream) which must have daily flow discharge data with gaps in the time series and the data in the two time series must overlap.

For example:

Gauge 1 gap: from 2-09-1980 to 7-10-1980

Gauge 2 gap: from 15-08-1980 to 2-09-1980

I am trying to find my answer manually on the NRFA website http://nrfa.ceh.ac.uk/data/search but it is not easy as the completeness of the time series is really good.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what I was looking for just by checking manually the gauges on the NRFA website http://nrfa.ceh.ac.uk/data/search .

In the map, if you click on the gauges you can go to the relative info page where you can see the completeness of the time series.

Really nice.